# How to include the severity of a log in the e-mail subject?

Tags: symfony, monolog

I'm using Monolog with Symfony2 and have configured a logging environment where everything is logged to file, and above a certain threshold are e-mailed to me. My config is below.

However, I have not been able to adjust the e-mail subject so that it changes based on the actual level of the log. The difference in response time, for say, a warning and a critical, would probably be different. Is there a way to do this?

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
        mail:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: %logger_level%
            handler:      buffered
        buffered:
            type:    buffer
            handler: swift
        swift:
            type:       swift_mailer
            from_email: %logger_from_email%
            to_email:   %logger_to_email%
            subject:    Log  # I want the subject to include the log level somehow
            level:      debug
```

Comment: I looked at the code for the Swift mailer handler and what you want to do is not possible. The subject is sent "as is", it is not interpolated or any other kind of transformation. Sorry!!

Comment: After posting this comment I had an idea for a solution, see below

Answer (score 0):

You can define two different handlers (or handler chains): one is activated by low level problems and the other by more serious issues. They have different subjects for the email they send. Something like:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        mail_critical:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: critical
            handler:      buffered_critical
            bubble: false
        buffered_critical:
            type:    buffer
            handler: swift_critical
        swift_critical:
            type:       swift_mailer
            from_email: %logger_from_email%
            to_email:   %logger_to_email%
            subject:    CALL 911, YOUR SITE IS BURNING
            level:      critical
        mail_debug:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: debug
            handler:      buffered_debug
        buffered_debug:
            type:    buffer
            handler: swift_debug
        swift_debug:
            type:       swift_mailer
            from_email: %logger_from_email%
            to_email:   %logger_to_email%
            subject:    Just a normal error
            level:      debug
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include **%%level%%** in the subject. It will add *int*.

Or you can add **%%level_name%%** it will add *string* of leg level name.

```
        swift:
        type:       swift_mailer
        from_email: '%env(ADMIN_EMAIL)%'
        to_email:   '%env(ADMIN_EMAIL)%'
        subject:    '[%kernel.environment%] [LEVEL CODE:%%level%%][LEVEL NAME:%%level_name%%] Some subject text! %%message%%'
        level:      error
        formatter:  monolog.formatter.html
        content_type: text/html
```

More can be found here https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/message-structure.md