# Symfony2 + Monolog: Different actions for different error levels

Tags: symfony, monolog

I have set up Monolog for our Symfony2 project to email out critical errors to us when they occur.

However I would also like to log non-critical errors also, and to email these errors out to different recipients. I am struggling to see this in the documentation however it looks like it should be possible. I have set up the config as follows:

```
parameters:
    error_mail_sender: error@mysite.com
    error_mail_recipients: [siteerrors@mysite.com]
    critical_error_mail_recipients: [siteerrors@mysite.com, developer@developers.com]

monolog:
    handlers:
        main_critical:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: critical
            handler:      grouped_critical
            bubble:       false
        main_error:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      grouped_error
        grouped_critical:
            type:    group
            members: [streamed, buffered_critical]
        grouped_error:
            type:    group
            members: [streamed, buffered_error]
        streamed:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        buffered_critical:
            type:    buffer
            handler: swift_critical
        buffered_error:
            type:    buffer
            handler: swift_error
        swift_critical:
            type:       swift_mailer
            from_email: %error_mail_sender%
            to_email:   %error_mail_recipients%
            subject:    Critical error occurred!
            level:      debug
        swift_error:
            type:       swift_mailer
            from_email: %error_mail_sender%
            to_email:   %critical_error_mail_recipients%
            subject:    Non-critical error occurred
            level:      debug
```

With this set up we receive the critical errors but don't get the non-critical errors.

This set up was loosely based on the (unaccepted) answer to this question: [How to include the severity of a log in the e-mail subject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481353/how-to-include-the-severity-of-a-log-in-the-e-mail-subject). (I would have up-voted the answer had it worked for me!!)

Can anyone spot what is wrong with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be bubble: false in the first handler, that means it'll stop propagating messages to other handlers.

Another note, I would remove the group and the streamed handler from grouped_critical, because it will already receive errors from grouped_error, resulting in duplicate entries in the log file.

So this should work:

```
parameters:
    error_mail_sender: error@mysite.com
    error_mail_recipients: [siteerrors@mysite.com]
    critical_error_mail_recipients: [developer@developers.com]

monolog:
    handlers:
        main_critical:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: critical
            handler:      buffered_critical
        buffered_critical:
            type:    buffer
            handler: swift_critical
        swift_critical:
            type:       swift_mailer
            from_email: %error_mail_sender%
            to_email:   %error_mail_recipients%
            subject:    Critical error occurred!
            level:      debug

        main_error:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      grouped_error
        grouped_error:
            type:    group
            members: [streamed, buffered_error]
        streamed:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        buffered_error:
            type:    buffer
            handler: swift_error
        swift_error:
            type:       swift_mailer
            from_email: %error_mail_sender%
            to_email:   %critical_error_mail_recipients%
            subject:    Non-critical error occurred
            level:      debug
```

I reordered them to make it easier to see the two handler chains as well.

Comment: A note for anyone else, this configuration will result in 2 emails being sent out for Critical errors, one for each handler. It is not currently not possible to prevent this as Seldaek explained to me here: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/issues/131#issuecomment-10884955